# Spring Interceptor path pattern issues

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I am having some trouble making the URL patterns used for Spring Interceptors work.

I am adding the path pattern programmatically, rather than in XML, but from what I understand it should work the same. I add it just like this:

```
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor(new AdminInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/admin.html");
    registry.addInterceptor(getRateLimitInterceptor());
}
```

If you don't add any path patterns, it applies to every URL.

I want it to apply to the following URL (assuming it's running locally):

```
localhost:8080/webapp/#/admin
```

That page gets its content by pulling from:

```
localhost:8080/webapp/admin.html
```

So I am not entirely sure which URL it is I need to block? Ideally, I would block anything with "admin" in the request URI, but I am not sure if that is possible. I have tried variations of "#/admin" "/#/admin" "admin" "/admin" but to no avail.

I'm sure it is just something very small I am messing up about the structuring of the path patterns. Any help?

Comment: Can you clarify what _to no avail_ means? What happened when you tried those?

Answer (score 0):

`#` is a special character when used in URLs. It denotes the start of a fragment.

If you want to send an HTTP request to a URL that contains a `#`, you must URL encode it with a `%23`.

In that case,

```
registry.addInterceptor(new AdminInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/#/admin");
```

will work, assuming you have a

```
@RequestMapping("/#/admin")
```

or similarly mapped handler method.

Comment: The mapping for this part specifically is all handled using AngularJS. Which might be the issue? Since I guess the calls are really just going to the root of the app and then it's handling that.

Comment: @elykl33t I don't understand your comment. If AngularJS is the client, open up your browser's network console and check what URL is used in the request.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was attempting to be too brainy there. I'm still fairly new to AngularJS. So from the console, I see that the request is going to "/webapp" for the page "admin.html" e.g. "/webapp/admin.html". Is there a good way to handle that using an interceptor path pattern?

Comment: @elykl33t If the request is to `/admin.html`, you can intercept it with `/admin.html`.